# join two columns with different sized arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

I have a table, as a result of query:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id,
       arrayMap(i -> i, range(1, o.quantity)) AS virtual_sku,
       s.sku AS sku
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_id,
                    groupArray(sku) AS sku
               FROM storage
              GROUP BY 
                    order) s
    ON o.id = s.order_id
```

| order_id | virtual_sku | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41273 | [1,2,3] | [12478431567,12478431568] |

In this example I have order 41273 with quantity 3 and two items from this order, received at the storage with unique sku.

I want to make this table

| order | v_sku | _sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41273 | 1 | 12478431567 |
| 41273 | 2 | 12478431568 |
| 41273 | 3 |  |

I try

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id,
       virtual_sku,
       sku
 ARRAY JOIN
       virtual_sku AS v_sku,
       sku as _sku
```

How can i avoid "Sizes of ARRAY-JOIN-ed arrays do not match" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used [enable_unaligned_array_join](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join) setting:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        41273 AS order_id,
        [1, 2, 3] AS virtual_sku,
        [12478431567, 12478431568] AS sku
)
ARRAY JOIN
    virtual_sku,
    sku
SETTINGS enable_unaligned_array_join = 1

/*
┌─order_id─┬─virtual_sku─┬─────────sku─┐
│    41273 │           1 │ 12478431567 │
│    41273 │           2 │ 12478431568 │
│    41273 │           3 │           0 │
└──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
*/
```